React Native: App crashes on first launch but works on restart, and APK shows "Unable to load script" error
I'm facing two issues with my React Native project:

App crashes on the first launch:

When I run the command react-native run-android, the app installs and runs on the emulator/device but crashes on the first launch.
After I reopen the app, it works fine without crashing. However, if the app crashes or restarts (for any reason), it crashes again.


Error when building APK:

When I build the APK and install it, the app crashes with the following error displayed on a red screen:

Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.


The app doesn't open at all, and I cannot proceed beyond this error.



Here’s my package.json for reference:
{
  "name": "Connect",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1305.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.87",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.87",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.87",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.87",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

I’ve tried the following solutions, but none have worked so far:

Running npx react-native start before launching the app.
Rebuilding the APK multiple times.

Any help or suggestions to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated.
What did you try?

Installed react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context with npm install.
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, then reinstalled dependencies.
Ran npm update and tried both upgrading and downgrading package versions.
Cleared Metro cache using npx react-native start --reset-cache.

What were you expecting?

Expected the app to run smoothly without crashing on the first launch.
Expected the APK to build and run without showing the "Unable to load script" error or requiring Metro.


When you are using emulator please see the network connectivity. If you are not connected to the network you see error.
